# Recording sound samples triggered by user using Howler

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

I have created a very basic sampler. There are a few audio samples that are triggered individually by a click event. A user is able to stop/play various audio files which overlay. The user can create a unique various of layered sounds and loops. What I would like to be able to do is record the audio of the unique experiment.

I would like for a user to be able to hit record and then the audio that the user hears, I would like to capture into a single audio file. This is before sending it to the server to potentially format and compress. I would like to know if its possible to record the audio as the user interacts.

I have seen various frameworks to simplify recording from the microphone, but have not seen a framework to be able to record from existing audio elements.

Any feedback is much appreciated.